# In gitlab or git command line, how to track which merge request a master branch commit come from?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a master branch for stable code, and only allowing fast-forward merge-request merging.

Is there any way in the gitlab or git command line to track the source merge-request of a specific master branch commit?

Or, I have to mark the merge-request info in the commit message and track it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Git itself would not track a fast-forward merge (except locally, for a limited time, with [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog))

Similarly, GitLab won't track fast-forward merges when [ff MR are enabled](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/fast_forward_merge.html), but you still have the GitLab API to [list present and past MR](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-merge-requests).
However, there is no "fast-forward" field in those queries.
Adding a [git notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) for instance would be a way to mark such MR.
That is what [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 216351](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/216351) is requesting.